# pageAction doesn't show in a browser popup window

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm not talking about the pageACtion's popup.html, but a browser window of type "popup".

I have an extension that shows a pageAction on a certain url (as usual).  But the pageAction's button doesn't show if the url is in a popup window.

Couldn't find anything about it in chrome extension's documentation.  Is it so, doesn't work in a popup typed window, or is it happening to me, because I'm using Ubuntu 13, for example?

Comment: It's not Ubuntu-specific. I can `window.open()` a new popup in Window 7, and I see neither page actions nor browser actions.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I conclude there may be so by design.

Comment: Probably so -- the menu button, bookmarks, and back/forward/refresh buttons are also all absent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @apsillers contribute, I conclude Chrome's popup window interface doesn't support browser actions nor page actions, by design.

chrome.pageAction.show on a popup window doesn't work, neither throws any error.

I think the location bar in a popup window isn't an omnibox.

Comment: Is there a workaround to be able to have an extension work on popup windows?  Can you share your code if you did it?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean.  Extensions actually work on popup windows.  Popup windows doesn't have an omnibox bar, neither a place to put a browser actions button, that's all; but you can execute content scripts like on any other page.