# How to write a Chrome extension that targets a window that's opened with "window.open()"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-docs

In Google Slides (the "powerpoint" of Google Docs), when you enter Presentation Mode, you can open the Speaker Notes window.  That window appears without a menubar so I did some research and concluded that it must have been created with `window.open()`.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this means that Chrome treats that window as a popup rather than its own independent tab.  I also noticed that when I view the Chrome Task Manager, that "popup" window is grouped together with the Presentation tab, rather than appearing as two tabs, which to me was further evidence that it's a popup.

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that works in that popup window, but I can't figure out how to target it.  Does anyone have any experience with something like this, or any pointers?

I tried treating it as a normal tab: I looked at the URL for the popup and just added a rule to have the extension appear on that URL, but it didn't.  If I change the rule to be on the Presentation (main) tab instead, then it does show up in the Presentation tab.  Again, I want to target the Speaker Notes popup tab.

Any information on how to deal with these kinds of "popups"/windows would be helpful (I only realized they exist 15 minutes ago)

Thanks!

This is how the processes show up in the Chrome Task Manager

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A popup opened this way is a window with a single tab in it.
You should still be able to interact with it normally through, say, `tabs` API.

However, it is a [known limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792862/pageaction-doesnt-show-in-a-browser-popup-window) that **page actions do not appear on popup windows** (that is, windows without the tab bar)

Comment: So if I can't use page actions, does that mean an extension that works in such a window has to be a browser-wide extension? I'm still very new to writing extensions so I don't immediately see how to communicate with that tab.  If you have an example of know of someone else's extension that works on these kinds of windows, I'd love to see to learn by example.  Thanks anyway

Comment: What do you need to do? _Any_ extension is, in some sense, browser-wide, a page action is just a UI element to show on some pages. If you need to trigger your extension by user action from a popup window, you will have to draw your own UI in it with a content script. If you don't need user action, maybe it's irrelevant.

Comment: I just want to run a snippet of JS on the popup window.  I originally wanted to have the extension icon in the address bar so that only if the user clicks on it the JS code will run, but I'm fine with giving up on the UI and just having it always run in the popup window.  Still can't seem to find the right way to run javascript in that window though.

Comment: [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). If you need to target them more precisely, `chrome.tabs.executeScript` from some event in a background page.

Comment: My problem was that the popup's URL in the address bar was "about:blank" so I had to add `"match_about_blank" : true,` to the `content_scripts` manifest.  Although I'm confused about how the URL shows up as "about:blank" yet when I type `location.href` in the JS console it shows me the real URL.  Can you shed some light on this? But more importantly - how can I check, using JS, if the content script is inside that "about:blank" popup or if it's in the main parent page?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this, I check the inspect element the popped up page.  Then I run window.name.  When I have that name, I can then use `var test = window.open('', window.name)`.  Now test has all of the elements I need.